# Git add -i и patch, можно ли выбрать все файлы, а не по одному?

Tags: git, git-add

То есть,

```
$git add -i  
$patch
```

а дальше все файлы, а не один.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет полезен этот вопрос: [Как добавлять файлы в Git по их номеру в отчете `git status`?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430471/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-git-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-git-status)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, наверное, хотите сделать `git add -p`?

К тому же в чем проблема заселектить файлы в patch списком типа

```
git add -i
5
1-5
```

Или вместо 1-5 можно шаблон использовать типа `*.pro`

```
git add -i
5
*.pro
```

Будут выделены все файлы, оканчивающиеся на `.pro`

Чтобы выделить все файлы, просто укажите шаблон, в который укладываются все файлы: `*`.

```
git add -i
5
*
```

Или, как я выше писал, - `git add -p`

Но мне лично редко когда требуется это делать. (Сразу все файлы отправлять в коммит.)

Comment: Спасибо, не знал за 1-5 и что можно шаблоны такие использовать, можно где-то почитать об этом? Нужно баш изучать или что-то другое? Я использую MinGw на Windows 7.

Comment: git add --help

Можно и Bash, хотя он свои шаблоны вроде юзает, но конструкцию из `git add -p *.{ui,cpp,pro}`никто не отменял (здесь будут выбраны все файлы, которые кончаются на соответствующие расширения).

Того, что я вам рассказал, достаточно, чтобы нормально работать и без знаний как такого bash.