# Как добавлять файлы в Git по их номеру в отчете `git status`?

Tags: git, git-add, git-status

Я часто сталкиваюсь со следующей ситуацией:

```
modified:   assembly/main.debug.s
modified:   ../src/cd/Config.java
modified:   ../src/cd/memoization/cfg/SubgraphFinder.java
modified:   ../src/cd/memoization/cfg/SubgraphMap.java
modified:   ../src/cd/profiler/Profile.java
modified:   ../test/cd/test/TestSamplePrograms.java
modified:   ../../notes/20150521.txt
```

Файлов очень много и у них сложные пути. Их неудобно добавлять из консоли, приходится вручную прописывать сложный путь. Я хотел бы добавлять их по номерам:

```
git magic-status

1 modified:   assembly/main.debug.s
2 modified:   ../src/cd/Config.java
3 modified:   ../src/cd/memoization/cfg/SubgraphFinder.java
4 modified:   ../src/cd/memoization/cfg/SubgraphMap.java
5 modified:   ../src/cd/profiler/Profile.java
6 modified:   ../test/cd/test/TestSamplePrograms.java
7 modified:   ../../notes/20150521.txt

git magic-commit 2,3,5 -m "Простой и удобный способ"
```

Как можно это сделать?

<sub>Для пометки связанных вопросов на разных языках: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411901/how-to-add-specific-files-in-git-by-their-number-in-git-status</sub>

<sub>Это перевод [собственного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30412128/2790048) с EN.SO</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Демонстрационный репозиторий:

Для примеров я использую репозиторий с четырьмя файлами: a, b, c, d.
Из них `a` - отслеживается, изменен, добавлен (tracked, changed and staged); `b` отслеживается, изменен, но не добавлен (tracked, changed and not staged); `c` не отслеживается, но добавлен; `d` просто ещё не отслеживается.

[image]

## 1. Отдельная утилита: [git-number](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number)

При запуске без аргументов, `git number` выполняет обычный `git status`, добавляя уникальный номер каждой выводимой строке с именем файла. Он "запоминает" соответствие номера файлу.

При запуске с аргументами:

```
$ git number <любая команда git> [одно или несколько чисел, и/или --аргументов]
```

`git number` запускает эту `<любую команду>`, заменяя все числа соответствующими именами файлов. Нечисловые аргументы передаются в git без изменений.

[image]

Пример с командой `diff` :

[image]

## 2. Отдельная утилита: [SCM Breeze](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze)

SCM Breeze - это набор shell-скриптов для bash и zsh. Он дает новые возможности работы с Git. Он интегрируется в вашу командную оболочку и добавляет упоминание файла по номеру, индекс репозитория с автодополнением по <kbd>Tab</kbd> и многие другие функции.

SCM Breeze использует горячие клавиши и псевдонимы (aliases) команд:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> => `git_add_and_commit` - добавить выбранные файлы и сделать коммит всех добавленных изменений.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> => `git_commit_all` - сделать коммит всех имеющихся изменений.

`git add`:

```
$ ga 1
```

`git diff`:

```
$ gd 2
```

`git reset`:

```
$ grs 3
```

`git commit`:

```
$ gco 4
```

## 3. "Родными" средствами: `git add -i`

```
git add -i
```

Из [Git reference](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> **-i**
> **--interactive**
> Добавить содержимое рабочей папки в индекс в интерактивном режиме...

Этот режим можно запомнить как `-i`нтуитивный, поскольку он невероятно понятен и удобен (по крайней мере, для бывалого пользователя Vim). Если не можете выйти из режима добавления, нажмите <kbd>Return</kbd> с пустой строкой.

Входим в интерактивный режим:
[image]

Добавляем измененный отслеживаемый файл:
[image]

Добавляем неотслеживаемый файл:
[image]

Смотрим на результат:
[image]

<sub>Если вам интересно, что это за консоль/цвета/оформление: [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) + [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) + [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)</sub>