# Выбираем частично файлы для коммита

Tags: git, git-commit

После проверки `git status` просматриваю мои файлы modified. Но как выбрать их по отдельности? - Поясню.
Хочу 9 файлов разбить на 3 коммита в каждом по n количеству файлов.

Comment: Думаю, вам будет интересен этот вопрос: [В чем разница между git add ., add -A, add -u и add *?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431839/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-git-add-add-a-add-u-%d0%b8-add)

Comment: И вот такой удобный способ: [Как добавлять файлы в Git по их номеру в отчете `git status`?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430471/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-git-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-git-status)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ git status 

Untracked files:
    1.json
    2.json

$ git add 1.json

$ git commit -m 'add 1.json file'

$ git status

Untracked files:

    2.json

$ git add 2.json

$ git commit -m 'add 2.json file'

$ git status

On branch master

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

несколько файлов добавляются так:

```
$ git add 1.json 2.json
$ git commit -m 'add 1.json , 2.json'
```

можно по маске:

- `git add .` - добавит все файлы,
- `git add m*` - добавит все файлы, начинающиеся на `m`.

Answer (score 6):

добавьте файлы в [индекс](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) (также его называют *stage*, *stage area* или *cache*) и после этого делайте коммит.

---

сейчас три файла модифицированы:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   file1
#   modified:   file2
#   modified:   file3
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

добавляем `file1` и `file2` в индекс:

```
$ git add file1 file2
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   file1
#   modified:   file2
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   file3
#
```

делаем коммит:

```
$ git commit -m 'добавили изменения в file1 и file2'
...
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   file3
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

и теперь можем продолжить то же самое (`add`+`commit`) для файла `file3`.

Answer (score 6):

Гит позволяет очень гибко коммитить. Можно закоммитить даже "пол файла".

Вначале пишем `git add -i` и переходим в интерактивный режим добавления файлов в коммит.

Будет выведено что то такое

```
$ git add -i
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
  3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb

*** Commands ***
  1: status     2: update      3: revert     4: add untracked
  5: patch      6: diff        7: quit       8: help
What now>
```

выбираем 5 (или p) и жмем enter. Дальше гит покажет список файлов и вбивая их номера, можно выбрать те файлы, которые будет "добавлять". в конце нажимаем enter.

После этого включиться специальный режим и Вам покажут по одному маленькому изменению (они называются ханки или чанки). С каждым этим изменением можно либо сразу добавить (y) или отказаться (n) или попросить гит разбить на более мелкие куски (s)

после успешного прохождения по всем кускам, просто выходим (q).

Теперь нужно посмотреть, что  же будет коммититься. тут помогут git status и `git diff --staged` (он как раз покажет что именно попадет в коммит).

Если все ок, то можно выполнить `git commit -m "text"` и закоммить.

Дальше этот процесс повторяется до получения нужно количества и качества коммитов.

Детальнее почитать о [этом на русском](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Этот способ очень удобный, так как позволяет не коммитить какой то временный код, который удалять не хочется (например, в целях отладки).

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы закоммитить несколько файлов нужно перечислить их имена: `git commit file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`

Comment: То что нужно, если несколько файлов в индексе и нужно сделать коммит только из некоторых.